# php Image upload file size limit?

Tags: php, image, file, upload, size

I have an image upload form for a client that I am having an issue with. I wish to set the file size to a maximum of 5.1 mb. However everything over 2.0 mb fails my if statement. below is the portion of the code I am using to qualify the file size. Are there limits to file size handlers that I am not aware of or does anyone see anything wrong with this expression? I am sure the expression is correct, as it works perfectly fine for images under 2mb. Thanks in advance.

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 5100000)     
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))
```

Comment: yes, I have various test files that I am using with different file sizes ranging from 1.98 to 2.02mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your `php.ini`? The default `upload_max_filesize` is 2MB.

Comment: I have, I changed it to 6mb. is that an instant affect type thing, or do I need to restart the server for it to take effect?

Comment: Yes, you need to restart your web server.